# cutting the triangle

Tags: geometry

I am considering the following problem and I would appreciate some comments.

Let $T$ be a triangle. For any angle $\theta$ (defined mod $\pi$), let $d_{\theta}$ be the line that divide $T$ as two parts of equal area.

When $\theta$ and $\theta'$ are distinct angles, define $M_{\theta,\theta'}$ as the intersection of $d_{\theta}$ and $d_{\theta'}$ (obviously this point exists and is unique, as the lines are not parallel).

1) Is it true that one can define $M_{\theta}$ as the limit point of $M_{\theta,\theta'}$ when $\theta'$ tends to $\theta$, or is it possible that this limit object is not well defined?

Under the assumption that the map $\theta \longmapsto M_{\theta}$ is well-defined:

2) What can be said about the set of points $\{M_{\theta},\theta \in [0;\pi]\}$?

3) Is it a continuous map?

4) What remains unchanged if one replaces a triangle by a convex polygon? (I guess things may go wrong for non-convex shapes...)

Maybe this is well-known, but I haven't found any book related to this problem... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Joffan That's not right. The triangle will balance on any line through the centroid, but that doesn't mean any such line bisects the area of the triangle. "Any of the three medians through the centroid divides the triangle's area in half. This is not true for other lines through the centroid" says your wikipedia link.

Comment: well actually I am quite happy this is not so easy as I was feeling a little bit stupid not having thought about it before...

Comment: so the problem is (too) easy for any shape that is stable under a central symmetry, like a parallelogram.

Comment: I consider the line $d_{\theta}$. It cuts the triangle T, the intersection forms a segment $s_{\theta}$ of length $l$. Put a point $M$ somewhere on this segment (at distance $t$ and $l-t$ of the boundaries of the segment $s_{\theta}$). If I draw the line of angle $\theta+\epsilon$, the change of parts affects areas whose order are $t^2 \epsilon+o(\epsilon)$ and $(l-t)^2 \epsilon+o(\epsilon)$. Thus, in order to preserve the equality of areas, (if $M_{\theta}$ exists), it has to be the middle point of the segment $s_{\theta}$. I don't know if it helps...

Comment: The text is not so clear. I suppose line $d_\theta$ forms an angle of $\theta$ with some reference line?

Comment: let's say the angle of a line corresponds to the argument of a generating vector mod $\pi$